# Can a user control be added to a Visual Web Part?

Tags: visual-web-part, user-controls

Can i add a user control to a Visual Web Part (in visual studio) in sharepoint 2010?

I have a user control which has content that i want placed on most of my visual web parts.

Has anyone got any sample code doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow two methods:

from msdn

> 1. In Visual Studio, open or create a SharePoint project.
> 2. In Solution Explorer, choose the project node.
> 3. On the menu bar, choose Project, Add New Item.
>      The Add New Item dialog box opens.
> 4. In the Installed pane, expand the SharePoint node, and then choose the 2010 node.
> 5. In the list of SharePoint templates, choose User Control (Farm Solution Only).
> 6. In the Name box, specify a name for the user control, and then choose the Add button.
>      Visual Studio adds several folders and files to your project.
>
>    By default, the user control file appears in the Source view of the
>      Visual Web Developer designer. In this view, you can edit the XML
>      markup of the control. You can switch to Design view if you want to
>      design the control visually by dragging controls from the Toolbox.
> 7. If you want to handle events that occur in the control, add code to the code file of the user control.
>
> This file appears in Solution Explorer under the user control file and
>   has a .cs or .vb extension, depending on the language of the project.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231548.aspx

in code you can do the following also taken from msdn ;) :

```
[ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public class VisualWebPart1 : WebPart
{
    private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/CS/VisualWebPart1/VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx";

    public VisualWebPart1()
    {
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Control control = this.Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
        Controls.Add(control);
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.RenderContents(writer);
    }

}
```

**Creating Reusable Controls for Web Parts or Application Pages**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231577.aspx

I think this is the one your looking for (url above :) with the code above explained )

or

http://thesoftwarecondition.com/blog/2012/02/22/how-to-add-a-user-control-to-a-sharepoint-web-part/

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I add a custom message control to almost every webpart I develop.
I put a PlacerHolder control on visual webpart and on page PreRender event I add that message control to PlaceHolder

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phMsg" runat="server"/>
```

Page PreRender Event

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add messages to page
    phMsg.Controls.Add(msg.MsgList);
}
```